# Ho do one submits parameters into model array in Yii

Tags: arrays, forms, yii, get

I have a written a form with the built in functions of Yii which works great. The form can be submitted when the user selects any of the dropdown-fields. The data is posted with the GET-method and the values show up in the url as key in an array. The array has the same name as the model for the form.

ex. url/index.php?r=controller/action&Modelname[y-value]=1&Modelname[x-value]=2

The problem is that when I want to add a submit button that should submit some extra variables those variables are submitted the normal way, without being included in the model-array. This means that I can't change the parameters of the model but instead new values are sent. What I want is for the parameters defined in the button to be submitted into the model-array.

ex. url/index.php?r=controller/action&Modelname[y-value]=1&Modelname[x-value]=2**&x-value=3**

My code for the button is:

```
CHtml::submitButton('X-value',array('name'=>'x','params'=>array('x-value'=>3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add the field to your form with the given attribute name? If you don't want the values to be visible to the user you could always add them as a hidden field in your form. For example;

```
echo $form->hiddenField($model,'x-value');
```

... assuming `$model` is your model and `x-value` is the model attribute. Although as you already seem to have a `Modelname[x-value]` in your submitted values, do you not already have a field for `x-value` in your form?

Comment: The problem is firstly that I want to change multiple parameters and secondly that I only want the parameters to be changed if I click the submit button. For now I am solving it with jQuery...

Comment: if you add your form code to your question it'd help show what you're trying to do, maybe someone can suggest something better.